# NetworkCredential(address, pass) returns null

Tags: c#, email, smtpclient

NetworkCredential(address, pass) returns null on clients ipad, but not on my test machines while using the same address and pass

```
SmtpClient smtpServer = new SmtpClient(mailServer);

smtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = false;

smtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(address, pass) 
    as ICredentialsByHost;

if (smtpServer.Credentials == null) {
    AV.Error("Mail credentials null -> email='" + address + "' pass='" + pass + "'");
}
else {
    send the email
}
```

The code runs fine on my test pc and my test ipad. On my clients iPad, it throws the error message because credentials are null. I can see its using the exact same address and pass. I have no idea why it would do that from their ipad, but not from mine.

Comment: What's the address?

Answer (score 1):

Setting UseDefaultCredentials =false should work for you. Add below lines of code.

not setting UseDefaultCredentials =false before credentials line  sometimes nullify the object which is very strange.

SmtpClient smtpServer = new SmtpClient(mailServer);

**smtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials =false;**

smtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(address, pass) 
    as ICredentialsByHost;

Comment: I'm actually already doing that, I just didn't show it in the example. I'll change it in the post.